# Why does this reduction not return -2?

Tags: javascript, math, reduce

I'm trying to return the lowest negative number, or -1 in case of none, from a sequence in a JavaScript array. Here is my code:

```js
console.log([1,2,3,-2,4].reduce((a,b) => {return b<0?(b<a?b:a):-1}))
```

Why does this return -1 instead of -2? Doesn't -2 get checked against the previous -1 value and returned?

Any clues might be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Replace `b<0` with `a<0`. `a` is the "accumulator" and `b` is the "currentValue": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: But b is meant to be the current value in this case; if it was not positive, I would not compare it against the accumulator.

Answer (score 3):

You could return the result of check if the element is smaller then the given initial value.

```js
console.log([1, 2, 3, -2, 4].reduce((a, b) => a < b ? a : b, -1));
```

Comment: Fails if -0.5 is present in array

Comment: because -0,5 is greater then the start value of -1. this solution works for integers, as the example shows.

Answer (score 2):

you can check it just by printing inside the reduce

```js
console.log([1,2,3,-2,4].reduce((a,b) => {
    console.log(a, b, b<0?(b<a?b:a):-1);
    return b<0?(b<a?b:a):-1
}))
```

when a = -2 and b = 4, your statement returns -1 since b > 0, you can fix this with

```js
console.log([1,2,3,-2,4].reduce((a,b) => {
    console.log(a, b, a<0?(b<a?b:a):-1);
    return a<0?(b<a?b:a):-1
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can reduce the array to smallest number and then return the value based on that, something like this:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,-2,4].reduce((a,b) => {return b<a?b:a});
if(arr[0] < 0)
  console.log(arr[0]);
else
  console.log(-1);
```

you can also sort the array using `.sort()` and then check for arr[0] and return the value based on that.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to give the initial value, it should look like that:

```
[1,2,3,-2,4].reduce((a,b) => b<0 ? (b<a?b:a) : a, -1)
```